# Count no of rows in uploaded excel sheet in Liferay AUI Script

Tags: liferay, liferay-aui

How can I find the no of rows in the uploaded excel file using aui script?

Please find the below ajax call.

I need to find the number of rows in excel sheet here.

function uploadFile(){

```
event.preventDefault(); 
A.io.request('${fileUploadCSV}', {
    method: 'post',   
    form: {
        id: '<portlet:namespace />uploadForm',
        upload: true,
    },
    on: {

         complete : function(e){

             console.log("complete");        

         }
   }
});
```

Comment: Please provide some script and excel upload code u have used

Comment: Added in question

Comment: As you won't parse excel files on client side, you'll not be doing this on client side, rather on server side, where you can have the tools to parse the file in Java (e.g. POI). Then it's a matter of how do you get it back. However, the way you phrase your question, the answer is "you don't"

Comment: As Olaf mentioned,you can parse it on server side.Probably post processing on server end,you can poll server for an update on the file specifications

Comment: Yeah, Thanks. I'm doing it in server side using POI library.